# How to increase the average Itemlevel

Tags: final-fantasy-14

My char is a level 34 Whitemage and had an average itemlevel of 22. After failed healing Titan in story mode I realised that my heal and my MP are to low to deal with the damage Titan is dealing to my mates.

I checked the market and bought a new staff, belt and shoes. After these changes my itemlevel increased to 25.

Now I equiped the best items I was able to find there but my average itemlevel is still 9 levels lower than my character level...
I read about level 50 endgame chars with an average itemlevel of 80 and I know it's because of the crystal tower raids, etc.

But isn't there a way to get a higher average itemlevel than the character level in midgame?

Click [here](http://de.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/character/6596232/) for my Lodestone link.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you equipping gear in ALL the slots? (ring, bracer, neck?)

Comment: Yes, only the shield slot is empty because I'm using a staff

Comment: Please provide a link to your Lodestone character profile so we can get a better idea of your current gear. If you're having trouble with MP, get an appropriate DoH and slot in Piety materia for you and use +Piety [food](http://ffxiv.gamerescape.com/wiki/Category:Meal). Higher ilvl gear on lvl 50 equipment is due to the level cap, only special quality items (HQ and from chests) under 50 are only slightly better then normal quality items. Make sure you have all of you [dungeon duties](http://ffxiv.consolegameswiki.com/wiki/Dungeons) unlocked, not all of them are unlocked via the story quests.

Comment: That looks like pretty typical leveling gear. The only thing that looks especially upgradeable is your Gridanian Ring, but beyond that, you should be good with what you have. Your currently-equipped weapon, however, is a wand (which is 1H), not a staff, so you can definitely use a shield with it.

Comment: @LukasWarsitz For Titan SM (syncs @ lvl 36) and other later dungeons, you need to leverage mobility and MP use. Focus on using Cure 1 and Freecures whenever they pop. Leverage Regen (lvl 35 WHM quest ability) whenever you can. If you have the THM cross-class skill Swift Cast, you can leverage this for emergency heals. You can also cast Stoneskin at the start and Regen to mitigate the damage throughout the fight. As long as the fight is properly explained, this fight shouldn't be all that hard.

Comment: Is there even anything that does a gear check prior to level 50?  Why do you feel the need to worry about item level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, I'm afraid there's no way to increase your item level beyond your level.  Not while levelling, anyways.  Every bit of equipment prior to level 50 has an item level that matches rather closely with its required level.  Only once you hit max level does that open up into higher item levels.

Comment: Not entirely true, a few (count on hand) rare pieces in the 20s and 30s are iLvl higher then equip, but usually are pink drops. And quite a few pink and even green in the 40's start being higher then rated (not even including the L45 AF gear).